# Classes of asymptotically normal statistics

Tags: normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, asymptotics

Consider an iid sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$, from a "well behaved" distribution
with pdf $f(X)$.

My question is the following: what are the classes of statistics $S(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ that are asymptotically normal?

I know about the asymptotic normality of specific statistics (such as the sample mean), but think it would be nice to have a list of all the families or classes of statistics that are asymptotically normal.
I think M-estimators are an example of such a class, but are there others?

Comment: "*a list of all the families or classes of statistics that are asymptotically normal*" - such a list might be infinitely long.

Comment: Maybe, but I guess that there are very wide classes that contain most of the statistics that can be used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

See book *Approximation Theorems of Mathematical Statistics* by R. Serfling. There you can find classes of asymptotically normal distributed statistics.

Comment: Thanks, that book contains quite a lot of relevant results!